# Play a sound on my computer when visitor clicks a button. {Collaboration ideas}

Tags: button, audio, playback, visitor-pattern

I have a room full of sales representatives. Currently, when they make a sale, they write it on the board and ring a bell next to the board. Lately we've been too busy for them to get up and ring the bell. I would like to have a small window or application open on their computer that has a button and then I have a separate window or application open that when they click the button it makes a bell sound. I do not want this to play on the other reps computers - just mine. Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can make a new dummy Facebook account, and the 'button' will be entering anything in the private messages, so you will hear a sound there. However, you will have to avoid using other Facebook accounts on the same computer.

Comment: This is an interesting concept. Each rep would need a FB account though? Facebook is blocked on their computers :/ - Does anyone else have any other ideas?

Comment: You can also install any IM software such as ICQ, and do the same. The same can be done with email: you can set up your mail client, if any, so that you hear a sound when you get messages from a certain address; and this address will be used for this notification only.